# Surface Laptop 2 Keyboard

Tags: usb, keyboard, surface

I installed Ubuntu on my surface laptop2. I am able to boot into the system. The touch pad works, but the keyboard doesn't. I am able to attach a USB keyboard and that works.

I followed instructions and installed the kernel from https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface

My inbuilt keyboard still won't work. The USB keyboard won't work either. Please help.

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and this device is  SURFACE LAPTOP 2.

Comment: Try this one. It seems more active. https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface, https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Supported-Devices-and-Features#feature-matrix Not having a surface, I can't say whether it would work, though.

Comment: Did any of these links solve the issue?

Comment: Sadly. No. I am still using this with an external keyboard.

Comment: You can open an issue in these GitHub repositories.

Comment: I have now wiped my surface laptop. I am in the process of shipping it to Microsoft. Thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps when it returns.